# How to solve the Appium WRITE_SECURE_PERMISSION denial error?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

[image]I tried to start the session in Appium with an Android APK . I given the three parameters like app location , platform name and device name but the when I start the session it shows an WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission denial error . Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: You need to figure which activity has android:exported=true, only those activity can launcher activity

Comment: @Mani I modified that, But still the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely your appPackage and appActivity is incorrect.

Shell in adb to find the apppPackage and appActivity

```
adb shell
```

Launch the app and type the below

```
dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'
```

You will see that the appActivity and appPackage. They are separated with a "/" example "com.vender.org/com.vender.org.mainActivity"
 
com.vender.org - appPackage

com.vender.org.mainActivity - appActivity

Source [link](https://medium.com/@ivantay2003/appium-desired-capabilities-basic-cheat-sheet-to-launch-mobile-application-ios-android-75b664367031)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this once:

1. In the developer option of your device, make sure all these 3 options are enabled.[image]